# Self referencing @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, spring-data, datanucleus

I have the following class

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends Base {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Comment inReplyTo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "inReplyTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Comment> replies;

public Comment() {
}

public Collection<Comment> getReplies() {
    return replies;
}

public void setReplies(Collection<Comment> comments) {
    this.replies = comments;
}

public Comment getInReplyTo() {
    return inReplyTo;
}

public void setInReplyTo(Comment inReplyTo) {
    this.inReplyTo = inReplyTo;
}

}
```

Adding a new Comment and setting the inReplyTo works and the comment is saved into DB. But the inReplyTo comment has the replies field null.

Also doing

```
c.setReplies(new ArrayList<Comment>());
c.getReplies().add(x);
repo.save(c);
```

results in this error

```
org.datanucleus.store.types.IncompatibleFieldTypeException: Incompatible type requested for field "Comment.replies" : was java.util.Collection but should be java.util.Collection
```

Any idea?

Comment: Initially, the text of this exception looks like nonsense as the 2 types appear to be the same. However, you could be looking at the possibility that datanucleus is getting the `java.util.Collection` from a different jar (version) to the one that your code is referencing. Check you don't have some sort of class loader issue.

Comment: Are you using Maven to build this project? If so, perhaps you can do a maven dependency tree to see if there are multiple dependencies on `java.util`.

Comment: Adrian, was it the class loader issue?

Comment: What version of DataNucleus are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gradle, Java 7 and DataNucleus 4.0.6. No, it wasn't a class loader issue, java.util is contained only in JDK.

Comment: I upgraded to DataNucleus 4.1.1, but no change.

Comment: Actually after upgrading to DataNucleus 4.1.1 and a clean-up, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to DataNucleus 4.1.1, did a clean-up and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have code similar to this:

```
Comment parent = //...

Comment reply = new Comment();
reply.setInReplyTo(parent);
reply = commentRepository.save(reply);

Collection<Comment> parentReplies = parent.getReplies();
```

and you are wondering why `parentReplies` is `null`.

This would be expected because §2.9 Entity Relationships of the JPA 2.0 spec says:

> *Note that it is the application that bears responsibility for maintaining the consistency of runtime relationships—for example, for insuring that the “one” and the “many” sides of a bidirectional relationship are consistent with one another when the application updates the relationship at runtime.*

DataNucleus is not responsible for instantiating a new collection containing the new `reply` Comment and setting `parent`'s replies property to this collection.  I have checked DataNucleus 4.1.0 and Hibernate 4.3.10 and verified that neither one will update the in-reply-to Comment's replies property.

Your application needs to make sure that the runtime relationships are consistent.  For example, you could add an addReply() method to the Comment class:

```
    public void addReply(Comment reply) {
        if (this == reply) throw new IllegalArgumentException("`reply' cannot be `this' Comment object because a comment cannot be a reply to itself.");
        if (replies == null) replies = new ArrayList<>();
        replies.add(reply);
        reply.setInReplyTo(this);
    }
```

Then the code for adding a reply would be something like:

```
Comment parent = //...

Comment reply = new Comment();
parent.addReply(reply);
reply = commentRepository.save(reply);

Collection<Comment> parentReplies = parent.getReplies();
```

Also, I am not reproducing the error:

```
org.datanucleus.store.types.IncompatibleFieldTypeException: Incompatible type requested for field "Comment.replies" : was java.util.Collection but should be java.util.Collection
```

Comment: I get the same error even if I'm trying to save the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You should set both parts of the relationship:

```
c.setReplies(new ArrayList<Comment>());
c.getReplies().add(x);
c.setInReplyTo(x);//this is the most imporant
repo.save(c);
```

If that does not work, it is probably a bug in Datanucleus: try to report it and put a link somewhere here.

Comment: @AdrianBer in addition to this answer, that I think is the right one, I want to ask you: are you adding a raply and checking the replies collection on the original comment within the same transaction?

Comment: This is what I did and I got the error in the question. I got the error when trying to save.